# How do you get Python to open a text file using print and input? I have the code I am using below

Tags: python, file, input

The code I have so far which is only producing an error is below

```
print(input("What is the text file's name?"))
file = input
openfile = open(file)
```

Any help would be appreciated! If you need more code/background please ask :)

Comment: try `file = input("What is the text file's name?")`

Comment: "An error"? Do we have to guess -- "Out of memory"? "Disk full"? "You need administrator rights"?

Comment: You don't have to use print to show the text from input. input("Question?") should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.x

```
filename = input("What is the text file's name?")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Python 2.x

```
filename = raw_input("What is the text file's name?")
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
```

Note that you may either use:

1. A file name if the file is in the current working directory, e.g.

> data.txt

2. A relative path from your working directory

> ..\folder\data.txt

3. An absolute path

> C:\Folder\Subfolder\data.txt